# D7: HTML email sent shows markup, how to fix?

Tags: 7, emails

Im using Linode VPS but mails are routed via SMTP authentication to Google. Email is sending correctly and I'm using mail system and html mail with smtp authentication.

When I send test email as html to test mailbox, it shows markup and wont render to html. How can I fix this?

HTML Mail > Send Test

Creating HTML mail and sending it with SmtpMailSystem sending class. Output when viewed at gmail receiving it:

```
<p>This is a test letter.</p>
<p>Lets add some <u><strong>html</strong></u></p>
```

So all markup is visible. What I'm missing?

Comment: Headers are wrong perhaps. Can you re check headers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Edited php.ini:
/etc/php5/apache2 # nano php.ini

-->

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t

Set mailsystem to htmlmail, voila.

Comment: Can someone clarify this a little?  I don't think php.ini needs to be edited (and this comment doesn't seem to actually represent any changes to php.ini - unless @Tumomas is resetting the default).  And "Set mailsystem to htmlmail" is an insufficient description of the configurations for the [mailsystem module](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem). This does look like the right track, but i'm having trouble understanding what the OP intended.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77608/drupal-7-webform-module-is-not-sending-email-properly#77852) says the same thing a little more clearly.